# constraining Page flow

Tags: php, http, architecture, stateless

What are the current strategies to constrain the user to follow a certain page flow. Obviously I can make a flow layer which will keep track on where the visitor goes, which will act like a kind of session layer. but I am more interested in the procedures there there is not much load on session or any persistent layer.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep track of the pages the user visits you will have to store that information somehow somewhere...

Comment: cant it be designed as a chain of token passing through GET params ?

Comment: google analytics has good pageflow tools

Comment: but that keeps a track only, can that procedure be utilized to constrain as well ?